# NoSuchElementException when calling another class

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to writing a game in which you explore and find resources, but when I try call the "explore class", it runs through this code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choose;
    boolean keep = false;
    do{
    System.out.println("Who would you like to send to explore?");
    System.out.println("=======================================");
    System.out.println(" *\t1. Simon                     *");
    System.out.println(" *\t2. Lily                      *");
    System.out.println(" *\t3. Axel                      *");
    System.out.println(" *\t4. Exit Exploring            *");
    System.out.println("=======================================");
    choose = scanner.nextInt();
```

returns to the main class and does:

```
System.out.println("===================================");
        System.out.println("\t 1. Explore");
        System.out.println("\t 2. Use Resources");
        System.out.println("\t 3. View Stats");
        System.out.println("\t 4. Sleep");
        System.out.println("===================================");
        option = scanner.nextInt();//where I believe the exception happened
```

it throws out the exception:`java.util.NoSuchElementException`

I have done `scanner.close();` at the end of the explore class, but I am uncertain it's causing the issue.

Can anyone explain to me the error in my code?

Comment: What do you enter when you get the exception?

Comment: You can [edit] your post and include sample input and output. Also, can you include the full code for the "explore class" part? I think this might be similar to another question where someone declared a `new Scanner(System.in)` and the closed it.

Comment: I did do scanner.close(); at the end of the code, is that the reason why it threw that exception?

Comment: also don´t close the scanner as long as you are trying to read from it. You are working on the same instance of the `InputStream`, if you close it at any point then you wont be able to retrieve any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
    option = scanner.nextInt();
}
```